# 'UnimplementedError' when exporting list to CSV in Flutter

Tags: flutter, csv, dart

I am trying to export list to CSV.

I have declared a 2D array.

[image]

used the below function which helps me export the declared array in CSV format which was suggested in my previous question and many blogs.

[image]

called this function from a TextButton() as below:
[image]

when I am executing it, an exception is being thrown as below in the console.
[image]

When checked, I got to know that this exception is because of "unfinished code that hasn't yet implemented all the features it needs"

Sorry that I am not able to share the full code since it is exceeding characters. I can provide more info if needed.

It would be great if you guys can help me on this! Thanks :)

Comment: I would recommend you to first locate where the error is thrown. 

So either put a breakpoint in your line `debugPrint('WEB_SAVE_CSV_EXCEPTION : $ex');`, or print the stack trace instead by changing the catch to `catch(ex, stack)` and then printing `stack` as well.

Comment: Hi Niko, Tried to print Stack and it says "flutter: #1      FileHelper.webSaveCSV |
Customer_Home_Page.dart:34 |
flutter: #2      FileHelper.saveCSV |
Customer_Home_Page.dart:24 |
flutter: #3      _CHPState.build.<anonymous closure>" . _CHPState is a class which extends a stateful widget. FileHelper is a class which contains webSaveCSV function which was already provided in the question.

Comment: Hi, what does it say at #0 above the #1? 

Probably its inside of the "ListToCsvConverter". 

Is that a custom package that you are using? And are you using the newest version of it?

Comment: "flutter: WEB_SAVE_CSV_EXCEPTION : UnimplementedError |
flutter: STACK : #0      Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob" I am using "universal_html" (universal_html: ^2.2.3) along with "csv" package (csv: ^5.0.2)

Comment: Sadly the "universal_html" package currently does not have an implementation for 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/Url/createObjectUrlFromBlob.html

Comment: Thanks Niko for letting me know. So, any other alternatives that you can provide ? I have tried dart:html but another issue was thrown "dart:html' is not available on this platform" which is why I have used that.

Comment: Uhhm, tough to say without knowing the scope and usecase of your app. 
I also haven't dived that deep into the web part of flutter yet. 

And yes, `dart:html` can only be used when building for web and not when building desktop, or mobile apps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254405/discussion-between-ram-kashyap-and-niko).